# jQuery - Adding css to localStorage variable

Tags: javascript, variables, local-storage

I have a variable retrieved using localstorage. On the next page I want to create a variable and add a CSS style to it before using it.

The variable in this is packageName, which works fine if I dont add the css. This is what I've tried below

```
var packageName = ((localStorage['chosenPackage']).css('text-transform','capitalize'));

$('.js-package-name').text('1 x ' + packageName + ' Profile');
```

But it returns Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.chosenPackage.css is not a function

Comment: Missing `$` but even still `packgeName` will be a jQuery object so not really clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl It prints out "packageName = gold" through console. What I want to do is make the first letter of "gold" Uppercase before I use it in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage only stores strings. So you're trying to apply CSS to a string. You'd want to do something like:

```
var packageName = localStorage.chosenPackage

$('.'+packageName).css('text-transform', 'uppercase')
  .text('1 x '+packageName+ ' Profile')
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for claryifying that. At least I know why its not working. You solution doesn't work in my case because I wanted to change the string with css before I use it. I found a work around by changing when I use by adding the css then.

Comment: I can't find exactly what I wanted but this solution provides a solid work around for me. Thanks